# Add div border with jquery without changing width and default border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make something like Inspect Element highlight. I want to add a border to divs on mouseover.

I don't want this to change the width of the div and also, there are some divs with their own border, so I don't want to replace the div's default border.

```
 $( document ).find('div').hover(
                function(e){
                    $(this).css('border', '1px dashed #59A3D5');
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                },function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).css('border', 'none');
                    return false;
                }
            );
```

That's what I tried. But it is replacing the div's default border (if it has) and it changes the width of the div... and it also border the parent divs too...

**EDIT**

I also tried to add a class to mouseovered div and use `:before` to add the background with position absolute, but it goes wrong if website uses positions relative and absolute:

```
            $(document).find('div').hover(
                function(e){
                    $(document).find('div').removeClass("highlight");
                    var current_div_position = $(this).position();
                    $(document).find('body').append('<style>.highlight:before { width: '+$(this).outerWidth(true)+'; height: '+$(this).outerHeight(true)+'; top: '+current_div_position.top+'; left: '+current_div_position.left+';}</style>');
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                },function(e){
                    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            );
```

And CSS:

```
.highlight {
}


.highlight:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: rgba(183, 226, 243, 0.4);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Add `outline` instead. It doesn't change the dimensions and will be rendered without interfering with the border. http://jsfiddle.net/fzhvf4v1/

Comment: You can use [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) if the element does not have one.

Comment: By the way, there is no need in `return false;` if you use `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();`. And vice versa.

Comment: @pawel I'd add that as an answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think you're right, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) instead. 
It doesn't change the dimensions and will be rendered without interfering with the border.

```
.highlight {
    outline: 2px dashed #0f0;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fzhvf4v1

Edit: as an alternative you could also use `box-shadow` to make the highlighted element "glow": http://jsfiddle.net/fzhvf4v1/1/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an element can not have 2 `border style properties` defined **at the same time**. Going about it your way, one border will always replace the other.

There are some alternative ways you could go. I would suggest, like @pawel already mentioned, use `outline`. If you have to use borders, then you can have another element `wrapping` your element, and add the border to this wrapper on hover. You can arrange it so this wrapper is invisible otherwise.

And, as a side note, since what you want to have is just a style change on elements hover, you **can** and **should** use css to achieve it. Look into css `:hover`.